# How to configure Systemd User Service with a Timer

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, services

I have a systemd user service that works as expected. It is started like this:

```
systemctl start test@user
```

The problem is that I need to run this service on a timer possibly for multiple users. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify a user in the timer itself or a way to pass the username with the @ notation.

Here is the timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test (runs once every 24 hours)

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=24h
Persistent=true
Unit=test@.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

What confuses me is what to put in the "Unit=".
If I put in "test@user.service" it works but then it will always run as a single user defeating the point of having a multi user service. Using "test@.service" starts the timer but "systemctl status test@user" shows it as always inactive even with timer set to 1min interval.

I am not sure how to list the all running instances of a given systemd service so I don't know if "test@" service is running as a different user when a timer runs the service without the "@user".

What is the proper way to start user services with a timer? Ideally users should be able to create and manage their own services as well as timers that go along those services.

Answer (score 0):

Does that answer what you need?

```
systemctl --user start unit.service
```

Comment: Adding some explanation why it would do so would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the service inside the timer like this:

```
Unit=test@%u.service
```

From `sytemd.unit(5)` manpage for the specifier `%u`:

> This is the name of the user running the service manager
>   instance. In case of the system manager this resolves 
>   to "root". Note that this setting is not influenced by 
>   configurable in the of the service unit.